# ImageResizer .net for multiple product images perfomance issues?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

I'm building an Asp.Net MVC4 Application with product pages. I have come by the [ImageResizer](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/) Library for handling and serving the images. My page has jpg thumbnails 160x160px in dimensions and 3~5KB size each.
To my understanding using the ImageResizer library i could just upload the original large product image 600 x 600px & 10~20KB and resize it on the fly to the thumbnail size when the visitor requests the page. Something like:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/images/imagename?width=160&height=160")" alt="">
```

Which i understand is fine for a couple of images but my product page consists of 20 to 100 product jpg unique thumbnails (depending on pagesize).
Should performance hurt with processing on-the-fly 20-100 pics each time? Has anyone faced a similar scenario? I could always go back back and generate 2 different images (thumbnail and large) during the upload process but i'm very curius if i could get away with just one image per product and dynamic resizing.
When i say performance i mean that anything above 0.5 - 1s extra response time is a no-no for me.

Answer (score 1):

In documentation it is mentioned, that there's caching plugin, which improves performance by 100-10000X:

> Every public-facing website needs disk caching for their dynamically resized images (no, ASP.NET's output cache won't work). This module is extremely fast, but decoding the original image requires a large amount of contiguous RAM (usually 50-100MB) to be available. Since it requires contiguous, non-paged, non-fragmented RAM, it can't be used a (D)DOS attack vector, but it does mean that there is a RAM-based limit on how many concurrent image processing requests can be handled. The DiskCache plugin improves the throughput 100-10,000X by delegating the serving of the cached files back to IIS and by utilizing a hash-tree disk structure. It easily scales to 100,000 variants and can be used with as many as a million images. It is part of the Performance edition, which costs $249. The DiskCache plugin requires you to use the URL API (read why).

http://imageresizing.net/plugins/diskcache
http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics

Comment: So i'm guessing you're saying that without the caching plugin performance for this would suffer. I'll have to go with storing 2 separate images due to the cost I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to websites, every operation that can be cached should be. This allows the server to deal with more visitors rather than more processing.

You could either use the caching plugin for ImageResizer, or manually write to file using a certain filename, e.g.: product_154_180x180.jpg where 154 is product id, and 180 is the width and height, then check for whether it exists when you want to display it.

If you do the latter, you may be able to use the server to manage this for you, by linking to the expected filename in the page source, and if it doesn't exist, the server then calls a script that resizes and writes the resized image to disk using imageresizer.

This last method will also avoid the call to ImageResizer saving you some processing power.

Comment: I don't think you've thought through the concurrency issues inherent in your proposed DIY caching solution. You're going to have a massive amount of deadlocked threads and files with orphaned handles if you try to do things that way.